# Decrease spacing between nodes and edges in forest

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I would like to decrease the spacing between start and end of an edge so that edged .

Take the following illustration as example (Left: before; right: after):
[image]

Code for the left tree:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}    
\begin{forest}
[A 
    [B] 
    [C]
]
\end{forest}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adjust the `inner` sep, the `l` and `l sep` options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[A
    [B]
    [C]
]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest} for tree={inner sep=2pt,l=10pt,l sep=10pt}
[A
    [B]
    [C]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `l'=10pt, l sep'=10pt` is quicker. @Paddre.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the hint. Could you explain why this the case and why `inner sep'=2pt` is not working?

Comment: @Paddre Because `inner sep` is a Ti*k*Z key and Ti*k*Z doesn't make a fast version available, whereas `l` and `l sep` are Forest keys and Forest does make fast versions available, which it calls `l'` and `l sep'`. You can say `l sep'+=2pt` for the same reason, but not `inner sep'+=2pt` or even `inner sep+=2pt`. Ti*k*Z doesn't support these keys. Perhaps it helps to say that `l'` is a *different key* from `l`. It is just that, by design, it does the same thing faster in simple cases.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the clarification. I always understood `'=` as an operator ;-)

Answer (score 1):

By using `inner sep` you can change size of the node

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}    
\begin{forest}
for tree = {inner sep = 1pt}
[A 
    [B] 
    [C]
]
\end{forest}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been looking for that parameter. Right after posting the question I realized that my image was not exactly representing what I was looking for (less spacing rather than longer edges). I was hoping, that less spacing keeps the edge length but apparently there is some other parameter I need to adjust. Do you know, how I can achieve something like shown in the updated image?